# Sonarqube Plugin for Confluence

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I would like to integrate my sonarqube instance with a confluence space, so all my team could have access to the project metrics. Does anyone know any plugin that does this or how to do it without a plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for badges, which allow you to embed a little image in a page with a metric name and *current* metric value. This is a native feature on SonarCloud.io, and coming soon for SonarQube. In the meantime, there's a [community plugin](https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-badges) you can use.

Comment: G.Ann many thanks for your answer. We contemplated badges' use, but unfortunately, it won't work for us due to security issues.  Here is why: if the security option "force user authentication" is set on our SonarQube instance, then all webservices become unreachable unless the user is authenticated. As a result, badges cannot be retrieved if this option is set. Moreover, SVG Badges plugin is currently not able to display quality gate badges if your SonarQube server is configured to restrict analysis execution rights. We don't want external users being able to execute analysis on our code

Comment: @A.Ollerson have you tried retrieving a badge with a user token?

Comment: thanks again :) We have tried to do it so, but the badges' web service does not allow to assign user token as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same need and a colleague recommended me to give this a try:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/es.excentia.confluence.plugins.confluence-sonarqube-connector/server/overview

We are currently in the evaluation stage, and quite happy with its use and functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dominique. We'll give it a chance. Best.